# Why there is an attributeError in MongoDB's collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

After running a script, I'm getting this error while I'm successful in yielding the data in .csv file.Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\softwares\anaconda\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Danial Taimoor\Desktop\facebook\facebook\pipelines.py", line 21, in process_item
    self.collection.insert(dict(item))
AttributeError: 'MongoDBPipeline' object has no attribute 'collection'
2018-08-02 10:06:04 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

**And here is the settings.py code**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'facebook.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline': 300,
}
MONGODB_SERVER='localhost'
MONGODB_PORT =  27017
MONGODB_DB= 'posts'
MONGODB_COLLECTION='fb_posts'
```

**pipeline.py**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from scrapy.conf import settings

class MongoDBPipeline(object):
    def __init_(self):
        connection=MongoClient(
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT']
        )
        db=connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection=db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

    def process_item(self,item,spider):
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        return item
```

This is my first try with mongodb!

Comment: Honestly, I can't understand what's the problem here, but I would recommend using `scrapy-mongodb` instead of implementing your own pipeline.

Comment: @stasdeep are there any restrictions regarding to chromedriver because I'm yielding data through selenium webdriver.

Comment: because without implementation of selenium webdriver, the same code is running ideally

Comment: It should not really matter how you get the data as long as you yield items from your callbacks.

Comment: `self.collection=db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]` is `WRONG` ! `self.connection = ....` is cursor, can call `self.connection[db_name][collection_name]` but need `connection.database_names()` and `connection[db_name].collection_names()` for valid input. On error : `self.collection.insert(dict(item))` don't use static variable , maybe `collection` is not iterable or undefined.